# Download icon embedded in PhantomJS screen render

Tags: phantomjs

Why do I see a download icon from screen capture using PhantomJS? The webpage I'm rendering does not show the download icon but the screen capture does. Where is that icon coming from?(see original webpage and phantomjs screen capture in images

[image: ORIGNAL WEB PAGE IN CHROME]

[image: IMAGE RENDERED BY PHANTOMJS WITH ICON???]

Comment: PhantomJS is a standalone browser. Either the developers didn't properly test their page for compatibility with PhantomJS (they really didn't) or they tried too hard and that is the result. Either way, we can't say why that is there, because we can't read minds.

Comment: I found that the icon only displays in firefox and phantomjs, so thanks for the help.